# Solr Suggester response weight and payload empty

Tags: solr

I'm using suggester with Solr. The suggestions response weight=0 and payload is empty also the result duplicated.
`http://localhost:8983/solr/mysql_core/suggest?suggest.q=ja`
the result

```
{
"term": "<b>jack</b>et number 2",
"weight": 0,
"payload": ""
},
{
"term": "<b>jack</b>et",
"weight": 0,
"payload": ""
}
```

How can I fix that?

my code as following:

```
 <searchComponent name="suggest" class="solr.SuggestComponent">
    <lst name="suggester">
      <str name="name">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="lookupImpl">BlendedInfixLookupFactory</str>
      <str name="indexPath">infix_suggestions</str>
      <str name="dictionaryImpl">DocumentDictionaryFactory</str>
      <str name="field">_text_</str>
      <str name="weightField">weight</str>
      <str name="suggestAnalyzerFieldType">text_general</str>
      <str name="buildOnStartup">false</str>
      <str name="buildOnCommit">false</str>
    </lst>
  </searchComponent>
```

```
  <requestHandler name="/suggest" class="solr.SearchHandler">
    <lst name="defaults">
      <str name="suggest.dictionary">mySuggester</str>
      <str name="suggest.onlyMorePopular">true</str>
      <str name="suggest">true</str>
      <str name="suggest.count">500</str>
      <str name="suggest.collate">true</str>
    </lst>
    <arr name="components">
      <str>suggest</str>
    </arr>
  </requestHandler>
```

```
<field name="name" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="false"  />
    <field name="location" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true"  multiValued="false" />
    <field name="_text_" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
<field name="weight" type="pfloats" indexed="true" stored="true" />

   <copyField source="name" dest="_text_"/>
   <copyField source="location" dest="_text_"/>
```

I try to use `BlendedInfixLookupFactory` instead of `AnalyzingInfixLookupFactory` but with no luck.

Comment: You're not setting a `weightField` or a `payloadField` - what do you expect these values to be?

Comment: @MatsLindh I though Solr 7 include it by default. I add the weightField, it's not working. please check my updated question.

Comment: Usually you want to use the `weight` field to associate a specific weight with each suggestion from a particular field (i.e. this document is more important for suggestions if a hit is received) - such as price. There's a bug in Solr 7 that returns 0 for all weights [if the weightfield is not present or does not contain a proper value](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-8343) (LUCENE-8343). This has been fixed in 8.

Comment: @MatsLindh I think we are talk on different things, right? I want to get how many duplicated I have. For example the "jacket" in my index is duplicated twice. and on my suggestion response appear only once with 0 weight. It should be weight = 2.

Comment: I think the bug will affect that?